# Unit testing of java Servlet with EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, testng, easymock

I wanna to test that my servlet throw a specific `Exception`, I'm new on EasyMock and I don't know which method I have to mock.

Here is my servlet code:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // get request's parameters to execute the query

    Map<String, String> parameters = null;

    // q = query name
    String query = null;
    if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {

        LOGGER.info("Parameters ({}) :", parameters);
    }

    parameters = transformParams(req);
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    if (parameters.get(QUERY_KEY) != null) {

        Resultat resultat = null;

        try {
            resultat = requestService.query(query, parameters);

            // construct file name
            csvConverter.writeToCSV(resultat, new FileOutputStream(
                    generateNameFile(SystemDate.getDate())));


            out.println(QUERY_EXECUTED);

        } catch (RequestNotFoundException e) {
            // request not found
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (RequestServiceException e) {
            // malformed request
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }

    out.println(QUERY_NOT_EXECUTED);


}

protected Map<String, String> transformParams(HttpServletRequest req) {
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // get query parameters
    for (Object key : req.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
        LOGGER.info("key :", key.toString());

        parameters.put(key.toString(), req.getParameter(key.toString()));
    }

    return parameters;
}
```

Here is the result of TestNg:

```
org.testng.TestException: 
Expected exception com.sqltojson.exception.RequestNotFoundException but got
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
last method called on mock cannot throw com.package.exception.RequestNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unit testing then you are testing only servlet class.
Exception would have to come from `requestService.query(query, parameters);` not from the servlet. It is only catched in the servlet. Because of that your expectations are incorrect.

In different words:
Your servlet will not throw that exception, only catch it and set appropriate status code. You should test if the status code has been set. And you should mock `query(...)` method to throw that exception.